# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory in pydub

Tags: python

I tried to change the pitch of the audio using pydub.
But when I set the path like that, I get an error ("FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory in pydub") that the path cannot be found.

The file (rec.wav) is in the specified path

What's wrong?

```
from pydub.playback import play

sound = AudioSegment.from_file('C:/Users/ddolcju/Desktop/새 폴더/rec.wav', format="wav")
```

Comment: don't you think the chinese (?) characters in the path are a problem?

Comment: Not solved yet

And the "새 폴더" is Korean

Comment: Sometimes you need a double slash with windows paths. Try `C://Users//ddolcju//...` Try this. Tho I'm just guessing. Don't have a windows so I can't test it out.

Comment: can you try from a path without the non-ASCII part? (ex; `C:/TEMP`)

Comment: Not solved yet .............

Comment: @ DuDoff Not sloved yet..

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be that you didn't add your ffmpeg's `bin` folder to **PATH**. Then restart your PC and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ***Visual Studio Code***
You should note that you have opened the working environment exactly from inside the folder where the Python file is located